Solving $\mathrm{e}^{\partial_x}u(x)=f(x)$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{e}^{\partial_x} u(x)=f(x),\quad x\geq 0
\end{align}
The formal solution is $u(x)=\mathrm{e}^{-\partial_x}f(x)$
the fact $[ {-\partial_x}, {\partial_x}]=0$ (Lie bracket) implies that (Baker-Campbell) $\mathrm{e}^{-\partial_x}\mathrm{e}^{\partial_x}=\mathrm{e}^{0}=I$ (identity operator).
Question 1. What will be a nice space of functions for that $\mathrm{e}^{\pm \partial_x}$ acts?
Question 2. Is there any reference where the Baker Campbell formula is applied but in the context of operators? (I usually find it in a matrix form, but I'm not looking for that)

If $f(x)$ is analytic with radius of convergence more than $1$ at every real $x\geq0$ then this is $f(x-1).$

Another way of thinking of functions $e^{\partial_x}u = f$ are as solutions to the IVP $u_t - u_x = 0$, $u(x,0) = f(x)$ evaluated at $t=1$ via semigroup theory. This allows you to extend the formal definition to classes of functions where the (potentially weak) IVP is well-posed, such as $L^p$ and Sobolev spaces.

If the exponential of the derivative is defined as
$$
e^\partial f:= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\partial^n}{n!}f$$
As an operator for some Banach space $\mathcal{B}$ then, by the Banach space version of the Cauchy Hadamard theorem, the series converges in the topology of pointwise convergence on the space of operators over $\mathcal{B}$ iif
$$
\operatorname{limsup}_n \left\|\dfrac{\partial^n}{n!}f\right\|<\infty$$
For all $f \in \mathcal{B}$
This is actually equivalent as being of Gevrey class 1. If the function are defined on a domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$ this is equivalent to ask that the function are analytic.
So the most natural set to define the operator is the set of analytic functions over a domain
For the second question, by a rapid Google search I have founded this that deals even with the case of unbounded operators
